# An executable compiled from source triggers a Windows Defender quarantine on just one computer

Tags: windows, anti-virus, dotnet-framework, windows-defender, workstation

Can anyone suggest next steps for the following virus alert scenario?

1. We have a new employee (located in the United States) who was shipped a brand new laptop directly from Dell USA.  It has Windows 11 Pro on it.
2. The machine is turned on for the first time by the employee while I monitor it over a zoom meeting.
3. After setting up Windows, we install the company's standard software using PowerShell and Chocolatey.  (Edge is only used one time to set up the Chocolatey environment.)
4. The system is then connected with our source code repository and our software is built from source code into a dotnet executable using command line tools.  The source code is 100% managed C# code.  The build process has no errors.
5. When the software is run, the executable is immediately quarantined by Windows Defender for containing the `Trojan Win32/Wacatac.B!ml` (could be a false positive if `!ml` implies machine learning).
6. There are 3 other identical machines in the company (located in Canada).  Two have windows 11, one has windows 10.  All the machines are Dell XPS 15's.
7. None of the 3 other machines trigger quarantine using the exact same steps to build and run the software locally.
8. All 4 machines are completely up-to-date with Windows, Chocolatey, and Defender patches as of 2024-03-14.
9. All 4 machines have the same version of the dotnet runtime and sdk compiler - 8.0.3.
10. All 4 machines compile the software from the same commit # in the source code repository directly to their local hard drive.
11. When the source code is compiled on a "good" machine and the executable copied to the "bad" machine it runs and does not trigger a Defender quarantine.
12. When I try to get a copy of the compiled executable from the "bad" machine for analysis, the act of zipping the executable (i.e. file-open) triggers quarantine.  I am afraid to flag the file as a false positive to get past this.
13. The new employee says they have not installed any additional software, and I can't see anything additional under installed apps.
14. Using Windows Defender, a Full scan of the machine does not reveal any threats.  Only Windows Defender Real-Time module seems to trigger the quarantine process.
15. The problem is repeatable and consistent.

The following forum question sounds similar but doesn't offer a workable explanation or resolution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-defender-detecting-trojanscriptwacatacbml/7c8eeb99-d529-4243-a8d7-b898bd67fc43

I understand that sometimes false positives will be generated by anti-virus software, but I would expect the response to be consistent across identically configured computers.

Can anyone suggest some useful next steps for identifying or fixing the issue?

Comment: Open a support request with Microsoft?

Comment: The computer is already infected by a virus. Delete everything and reinstall the OS.

Comment: No one will be able to tell you why any security solution is quarantining a file. You need to contact the vendor.

Comment: Ok, I will factory reset the machine and start again.  Thanks.